# two errors emerge while trying downloading and adding wineHQ repository

Tags: wine

After I typed and executed the following command line, two errors occrued, can anyone tell me the reason and solutions? I'm using ubuntu 20.04. Thanks !

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'

errors:

E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)

E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: You could look at entry 58 in /etc/apt/sources.list . Does it look reasonable?

Comment: Thank you, it worked.